# Comparing two unicode strings in PHP

Tags: php, string, unicode, utf-8, compare

I am stuck in comparing two unicode strings in PHP which both contain the special char 'ö'. One string comes from `$_GET`, the other one is a filesystem's folder name (`scandir()`). Both strings seem to be equal to me, making a

```
var_dump($filter);
var_dump($tail . '/' . $k);
```

on them also shows their equality but with **different** string lenghts (?!):

```
string '/blöb' (length=7)
string '/blöb' (length=6)
```

My snippet comparing them looks as follows:

```
if($filter == ($tail . '/' . $k)) {
    /* ... */
}
```

What's going on here?

**Additional information:** `$tail` is an empty string:

```
string '' (length=0)
```

Comment: What does `print_r(unpack("H*",$k))` return in your two cases?

Comment: Remember that some filesystems use NFD (or close to it), and you are probably thinking NFC.  You need to normalize to the same thing if you want to do a binary comparison. But doing binary comparisons on text is ill-advised. You need to use the UCA for text comparisons. See my [seven-language talk on Unicode](http://training.perl.com/OSCON2011/index.html) from OSCON this past week.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence and use this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.normalizer.php

You probably have a decomposed character in the longer string, meaning an o and then a umlaut combining character which overlays the previous character.

The normalizer function will fix things like that.

As a side note you should always normalize your input if you are using it for equivalence (for example a username - you want to make sure two people don't choose the same username, even if the binary representation of the string happens to be different).

Comment: This answer requires [`intl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) be installed. So if you have it, then why not use [`collator_compare`](http://php.net/manual/en/collator.compare.php)?  I'm searching for an answer that does not use `intl`...

Comment: @user9645 So you want to handle unicode strings, with all their *massive* complexity, without actually installing a library that knows how to handle unicode? I don't see how that would be possible.

Comment: Ariel - No I just want an alternative to GNU intl. That's all.

Comment: @user9645 intl is not GNU, it's from the ICU library (originally written by Talligent and IBM and then Sun), which is *the* definitive unicode library and is actually part of unicode. No one uses anything else anymore. You can try `iconv` and `uconv` but I don't think can do this, and are also no longer maintained. Can you tell me why you want to avoid intl?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try parsing them through utf8_encode() and checking them there? PHP doesn't support unicode and therefore advises to use utf8_encode/decode for some basic Unicode features.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: Thanks for replying my question. I am voting for you.