# My if statements isn't working when should work

Tags: php, variables, if-statement

I hope this isn't a stupid question but I'm stacked for hours here... This is what the script prints when I run:

```
print $campeonatosExistentesNOME[$h] . $nameOfChampionship[$t];

SÃ©rie ASÃ©rie A
```

**additional info:**

```
Campeonato CariocaCampeonato Carioca Campeonato GauchoCampeonato Gaucho
```

Take a look at my code:

```
if ($temporadaExistentesNOME[$f] == $seasonOfChampionship[$t]) {

        for($h = 0; $h < count($campeonatosExistentesID); $h++) {

                print $campeonatosExistentesNOME[$h] . $nameOfChampionship[$t];

                if ( $campeonatosExistentesNOME[$h] == $nameOfChampionship[$t] ) {

                    print "oi";
                    $campEtemp = $seasonOfChampionship[$t] . " " .  $nameOfChampionship[$t];
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO `campeonatotemporada`(Nome,IDTemporada,IDCampeonato) VALUES ('" . $campEtemp . "','" .  $temporadaExistentesID[$t] . "','" . $temporadaExistentesID[$i] .  "','" . $temporadaExistentesID[$f] . "')" ;
                    print $sql;

                }

        }

}
```

If SÃ©rie A == SÃ©rie A or Campeonato Gaucho == Campeonato Gaucho (additional info), what isn't working?

Comment: Check that your values are both using the same charset

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855425/comparing-two-unicode-strings-in-php

Comment: When prints Campeonato GauchoCampeonato Gaucho the charset is the same, no?

Comment: from where you getting these values? from a database or user submitted or from what?

Comment: One of the array have data from database and another one with data parsed with simplehtmldom.

Comment: try `"$campeonatosExistentesNOME[$h]" == "$nameOfChampionship[$t]"` in if statement. make sure it is double quote. it will convert values to string type

Comment: if ( "$campeonatosExistentesNOME[$h]" == "$nameOfChampionship[$t]" ) {
     
      print "hey";
      
     
     } Not working... :(

Comment: if you sanitize data, like addslashes(), it should do for both.

Comment: I tried this: $var1 =  addslashes($campeonatosExistentesNOME[$h]);
     $var2 =  addslashes($nameOfChampionship[$t]);
     if ( $var1 == $var2 ) {
}
and isn't working.

Comment: When prints Campeonato GauchoCampeonato Gaucho the charset is the same, no? @MarkBaker

Comment: may be there are spaces between words or something. your modified code has no "" marks to convert it to string.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.ctype.php - you can check for types.

Comment: Try var_dump() with both values, see if they have the same length

Comment: Hey @MarkBaker, I got this:

    string(8) "SÃ©rie A"
    string(10) "SÃ©rie A "

I should just remove tha spaces or do other thing to make this two values equals? Here in string(10) "SÃ©rie A " there is just 9 chars with space and not 10. You know why? Thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest using trim() before comparing, or figure out why the second value has those additional whitespace characters

Comment: @MarkBaker . Thank you! I tried trim() and worked. Thank you again!!!!