# How do you validate a html unicode in php

Tags: php, html

I am passing values from HTML form to a php file for processing

```
   $to_do = $_POST['action'];
```

Then i can say

```
    <?php
        if( $to_do == "delete") {
           echo "i will delete for you";
           }
      ?>
```

Difficulty i am having is when the HTML value is unicode &#10008 for a delete symbol.
instead of the value "delete".
In php i cannot tell how to test it.

```
    <?php
        if( $to_do == "&#10008") {
           echo "i will delete for you";
           }
      ?>
```

is not working.
Any one to help me out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two unicode strings in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855425/comparing-two-unicode-strings-in-php)

Comment: @kiner_shah thanks for suggestion. i do not know what they are asking there. i hope my question is clear though.

Comment: You want to compare two Unicode strings right? Read the question and answer in that link, maybe it's related to your issue.

Comment: How are you sending this value to begin with - `<input type="submit" value="✘">`? In that case, I would recommend you switch to a `button` element - that can have a separate submission value and display text. So you can keep _sending_ `delete`, and _show_ `✘` to the user at the same time.

Comment: @Cbro yes i am doing exactly that <input type="submit" value="✘"> Can you please give an answer of what you mean separately

Comment: `<button type="submit" value="delete">✘</button>` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you sending this value to begin with - via something like `<input type="submit" value="✘">`?

In that case, I would recommend you switch to a `button` element - that can have a separate submission value and display text. So you can keep *sending* `delete`, and *show* `✘` to the user at the same time.

```
<button type="submit" value="delete">✘</button>
```

More details on the `button` element can be found in the MDN, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button